# Outlook: Move 'flag status' index column to the left

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, inbox

In the 'Messages' (inbox) view in Outlook 2007, there is a list of all messages (one liners) with several field. The rightmost field is the 'Flag Status' field.

[image]

I'm trying to move this icon to the left. All other columns are movable (via several methods), but this status icon is not.

How can I move it to the left of the headers line?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I found DavHeili's suggestion [here](http://goo.gl/UL94d9) to be a suitable workaround. 

His suggestion: "As another alternative, You can leave the Flag Status where it is, and then use Conditional Formatting to create a rule on the "More Choices" tab where "Only items which: are flagged by me" is selected.  I changed the font to Bold Italic Maroon.  This way the whole message appears highlighted when the flag is set.  And it un-highlights as soon as you uncheck it.  That's my 2 cents worth."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in Outlook.

If you right click on the columns and click "Customise current view" you can then choose the top option which is fields.

On the right hand side, there is a item called "Flag Status".

I have tried moving it a few times, and whatever I choose, it stays as the last column, even if when I go back to the "show fields" screen, it is still first.

I have tried a few other methods, but this looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

2020 and Outlook still inscrutably locks the flag column on the right edge instead of allowing users to move it the same way they move any other column. When trying to move the column there is no error, no message, the software lets you go through the same motions as with any other column -then just doesn't do it. Astounding that a program used by so many people still has the same bug in their interface for over a decade.

I found one reference that said there is some "quick flag" option somewhere that needs to be turned off. Apparently that option overrides the user choice of moving the flag. Unfortunately the author of the article did not DATE the article or mention version of Outlook. The path he provided no longer exists in the Outlook menus scattered around the screen or little pictures in the "ribbon".

Answer (score 0):

I managed to delete the "Flag Status", by right clicking and choosing "Remove this Column". However I was unable to drag it back off from the "Field Chooser" window. The only way of retriving this column was to reset the view to its original settings, by selecting View, Current View, Customize Current View, Reset Current View, and then reajusting if necessary the view to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

To reposition the Flag Status column, you need to remove it from the view first, then restore it in the desired position. To remove the Flag Status column, choose View, Arrange By, Current View, Customize Current View, then click Fields. In the Fields dialog box, select Flag Status, then click Remove. Click OK once to return to the Customize View dialog box. To restore the column in its new location, click Fields again. In the Fields dialog box, drag Flag Status from the Available Fields list into the Show these fields in this order list, positioning it as you want it to appear in the view

Comment: This doesn't actually work in Outlook 2007 (for me).  No matter where the flag is in the field column, it always shows up on the right.